# F key doesn’t work in the tty

Tags: linux, keyboard, tty

My `“f”` key doesn’t work in the tty. I already tried most of my other keys on the keyboard and all of them work fine, even symbols like `Ü Ä Ö.` The `“f”` works completely fine on the login screen and on gnome, xfce, lxqt.
Im am using Fedora 35.\

EDIT:
I did not actively configure a global short cut.
Nothing happens when I press `f`. I am able to write while pressing the `f` key like he doesn't even exist.

Yes shift-F works, but I need a small f and shift-F results in `"F"`

vconsole.conf in etc says:

```
KEYMAP="de-e2"
FONT="eurlatgr"
```

Something very interesting.
F = “”
Shift + F = “F”
Cap lock on + F = “”
Cap lock on + Shift + F = “”

O.K. O.K. this just got a little bit weirder .

When I am pressing `“g”` and `“f”` super fast and at leased 10 times the tty shows this `“gggggggßßßßggggßßgggg ....”` somehow after a while of really fast pressing the keys the `f` does recognized as `“ß”`. And the same thing is also true for the `“d” + “f” variant with the differences that “`” Symbols appear. (every key combined with `“f”` shows new Symbols)
Something else very strange with my keyboard is that it stops writing in the python3 terminal after a while until I leave it with `“Ctr + Z”`. I don’t know if they are connected, but I wanted to mention it.

It appears like the `f` key does get recognized like the `“Alt Gr”` (the key on the right side of the `space` key) when it is pressed fast in combination with a other key.

The Original `“Alt Gr”` still works normal.

Comment: Did someone configure a stupid global shortcut?

Comment: Does shift-F work?

Comment: What happens if you put "f": "f" in ~/.inputrc?

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Aha! I just checked back and saw that shift-F works. That's very interesting! (You could notify me that you added the info with @Nick.) That makes me suspect something is screwy with your keymap. Do you have a file /etc/vconsole.conf, and if so, what's in it?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you haven't fixed something in the meantime, does activating caps lock and then typing shift-F give you a lowercase f?

Comment: @NickMatteo I updated the post